# CGBitmapContextCreateImage - vm_copy failed - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgimage

I am having an issue using CGBitmapContextCreateImage in my iPhone app.

I am using AV Foundation Framework to grab camera frames using this method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    self.imageView.image = image;

    CGImageRelease(newImage);

}
```

However, I am seeing an error in the debug console as its runs:

```
<Error>: CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData: vm_copy failed: status 2.
```

Has anyone ever seen this? By commenting out lines I have narrowed the problem line out to:

```
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
```

but I am not sure how to get rid of it.  Functionally, it works great.  So clearly, the CGImage is being created, but I need to know what is causing the error so it doesn't affect other parts.

Many thanks. Any help/advice would be great!
Brett

Comment: I am having the same problem with the same code. But the problem only appears on iPhone 3G devices on iOS 4. It works without any problems on an iPhone 4 or iPhone 3GS. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm that the fix I presented below does work. I got the vm_copy message on a 3G with iOS 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>*Disclaimer: this is pure speculation.*</strike> Not anymore.

`vm_copy()` is a kernel call to copy virtual memory from one place to another ([manpage](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xholer/macosx/xnu/vm_copy.html)).

The return value you get is KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE, "The source region is protected against reading, or the destination region is protected against writing."

So for some reason CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData calls this to copy some memory, and fails. *maybe* it is just trying vm_copy as a fast method first, and then falls back to a slower method (since you say everything works).

If you `malloc` a chunk of memory, memcpy the memory from baseAddress to your own memory, and use that to create the image, the warning vanishes. So:

```
uint8_t *tmp = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
int bytes = ... // determine number of bytes from height * bytesperrow
uint8_t *baseAddress = malloc(bytes);
memcpy(baseAddress,tmp,bytes);

// unlock the memory, do other stuff, but don't forget:
free(baseAddress);
```

Comment: ps. yes I know the manpage is a random link about Mac OS X, but I guess it applies to iOS too.