# AVCaptureSession returning blank image on iPhone 3G only

Tags: iphone, ios4, avcapturesession

I'm using Apple's example code for AVCaptureSession, and the UIImage that gets created is completely blank. This only happens on the iPhone 3G, along with a unique error that shows up on console that says -

> Error: CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData: vm_copy failed: status 2.

I've researched the error online and found this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367849/cgbitmapcontextcreateimage-vm-copy-failed-iphone-sdk), and it gets rid of the error...but the image is still blank.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

My Code -

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

CGContextRelease(context); 
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

return image;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something funky in the API so the work around that I'm using is:

```
//void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);     
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);     
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);     
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);     

// vm_copy fails on older model phones...    
//    
uint8_t *baseAddress = malloc( bytesPerRow * height );    
memcpy( baseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer), bytesPerRow * height );

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();     

// NO ALPHA CHANNEL ON OLDER MODELS    
// CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);     
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);     
CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);     

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);    
CGContextRelease(context);     
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
free( baseAddress );

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];    
CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

return image;
```