# Capturing a preview image with AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Before stackoverflow members answer with "You shouldn't. It's a privacy violation" let me counter with why there is a legitimate need for this.

I have a scenario where a user can change the camera device by swiping left and right. In order to make this animation not look like absolute crap, I need to grab a freeze frame before making this animation.

The only sane answer I have seen is capturing the buffer of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, which is fine, but now I can't let the user take the video/photo with kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange which is a nightmare trying to get a CGImage from with `CGBitmapContextCreate`  See [How to convert a kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange buffer to UIImage in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201084/how-to-convert-a-kcvpixelformattype-420ypcbcr8biplanarfullrange-buffer-to-uiimag)

When capturing a still photo are there any serious quality considerations when using  `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` instead of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`? Since the user will be taking both video and still photos (not just freeze-frame preview stills) Also, can some one "Explain it to me like I'm five" about the differences between `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange`/`kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` besides one doesn't work on old hardware?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to directly capture a preview image using AVFoundation.  You could however take a capture the preview layer by doing the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(previewView.frame.size);
[previewLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Where previewView.layer is the 
previewLayer is the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer added to the previewView.  "image" is rendered from this layer and can be used for your animation.