# How to convert YUV frames (from OTVideoFrame) to CVPixelBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, core-video

I need to convert YUV Frames to CVPixelBuffer that I get from [OTVideoFrame](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTVideoFrame.html) Class

This class provides an array of planes in the video frame which contains three elements for **y,u,v** frame each at index **0,1,2**.

> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSPointerArray *planes

and [format](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTVideoFormat.html#//api/name/pixelFormat) of the video frame

> @property (nonatomic, retain) OTVideoFormat *format

That contains Properties like width, height, bytesPerRow etc. of the frame

I need to add filter to the image I receive in the form of **OTVideoFrame**, I have already tried these answers :

- [How to convert from YUV to CIImage for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659671/how-to-convert-from-yuv-to-ciimage-for-ios)
- [Create CVPixelBuffer from YUV with IOSurface backed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823673/create-cvpixelbuffer-from-yuv-with-iosurface-backed)

These two links have the solutions in Objective-C but I want to do it in swift. One of the answers in second link was in swift but it lacks some information about the **YUVFrame** struct that the answer has reference to.

The Format that I receive is **NV12**

Here is what I have been trying to do till now but I don't know how to proceed next :-

```
 /**
 * Calcualte the size of each plane from OTVideoFrame.
 *
 * @param frame The frame to render.
 * @return tuple containing three elements for size of each plane
 */
fileprivate func calculatePlaneSize(forFrame frame: OTVideoFrame)
        -> (ySize: Int, uSize: Int, vSize: Int){
            guard let frameFormat = frame.format
                else {
                    return (0, 0 ,0)
            }
            let baseSize = Int(frameFormat.imageWidth * frameFormat.imageHeight) * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size
            return (baseSize, baseSize / 4, baseSize / 4)
    }

/**
 * Renders a frame to the video renderer.
 *
 * @param frame The frame to render.
 */
func renderVideoFrame(_ frame: OTVideoFrame) {


    let planeSize = calculatePlaneSize(forFrame: frame)
    let yPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.ySize)
    let uPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.uSize)
    let vPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.vSize)

    memcpy(yPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 0), planeSize.ySize)
    memcpy(uPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 1), planeSize.uSize)
    memcpy(vPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 2), planeSize.vSize)

    let yStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 0) as! Int
    // multiply chroma strides by 2 as bytesPerRow represents 2x2 subsample
    let uStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 1) as! Int
    let vStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 2) as! Int

    let width = frame.format!.imageWidth
    let height = frame.format!.imageHeight

    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    var err: CVReturn;


    err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(width), Int(height), kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, nil, &pixelBuffer)
    if (err != 0) {
        NSLog("Error at CVPixelBufferCreate %d", err)
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

Taking Guidance from those two links I tried to create Pixel buffer but I got stuck every time at this point because the conversion of the Objective-C code after this is not similar to what we have in Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for a fast solution, I did with `swift Accelerate`
using `vImageConvert_AnyToAny(_:_:_:_:_:)` function.

```swift
import Foundation
import Accelerate
import UIKit
import OpenTok
class Accelerater{


    var infoYpCbCrToARGB = vImage_YpCbCrToARGB()
    init() {
        _ = configureYpCbCrToARGBInfo()
    }

    func configureYpCbCrToARGBInfo() -> vImage_Error {
        print("Configuring")
        var pixelRange = vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange(Yp_bias: 0,
                                                 CbCr_bias: 128,
                                                 YpRangeMax: 255,
                                                 CbCrRangeMax: 255,
                                                 YpMax: 255,
                                                 YpMin: 1,
                                                 CbCrMax: 255,
                                                 CbCrMin: 0)

        let error = vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion(
            kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_601_4!,
            &pixelRange,
            &infoYpCbCrToARGB,
            kvImage420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8,
            kvImageARGB8888,
            vImage_Flags(kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole))



        print("Configration done \(error)")
        return error
    }

    public func convertFrameVImageYUV(toUIImage frame: OTVideoFrame, flag: Bool) -> UIImage {

        var result: UIImage? = nil
        let width = frame.format?.imageWidth ?? 0
        let height = frame.format?.imageHeight ?? 0
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        _ = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(width), Int(height), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &pixelBuffer)

        _ = convertFrameVImageYUV(frame, to: pixelBuffer)
        var ciImage: CIImage? = nil
        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer {
            ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        }

        let temporaryContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        var uiImage: CGImage? = nil
        if let ciImage = ciImage {
            uiImage = temporaryContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer!), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer!)))
        }

        if let uiImage = uiImage {
            result = UIImage(cgImage: uiImage)
        }
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, [])
        return result!

    }

    func convertFrameVImageYUV(_ frame: OTVideoFrame, to pixelBufferRef: CVPixelBuffer?) -> vImage_Error{
        let start  = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        if pixelBufferRef == nil {
            print("No PixelBuffer refrance found")
            return vImage_Error(kvImageInvalidParameter)
        }

        let width = frame.format?.imageWidth ?? 0
        let height = frame.format?.imageHeight ?? 0
        let subsampledWidth = frame.format!.imageWidth/2
        let subsampledHeight = frame.format!.imageHeight/2
        print("subsample height \(subsampledHeight) \(subsampledWidth)")
        let planeSize = calculatePlaneSize(forFrame: frame)

        print("ysize : \(planeSize.ySize) \(planeSize.uSize) \(planeSize.vSize)")
        let yPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.ySize)
        let uPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.uSize)
        let vPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.vSize)

        memcpy(yPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 0), planeSize.ySize)
        memcpy(uPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 1), planeSize.uSize)
        memcpy(vPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 2), planeSize.vSize)

        let yStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 0) as! Int
        // multiply chroma strides by 2 as bytesPerRow represents 2x2 subsample
        let uStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 1) as! Int
        let vStride = frame.format!.bytesPerRow.object(at: 2) as! Int

        var yPlaneBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: yPlane, height: vImagePixelCount(height), width: vImagePixelCount(width), rowBytes: yStride)

        var uPlaneBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: uPlane, height: vImagePixelCount(subsampledHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(subsampledWidth), rowBytes: uStride)




        var vPlaneBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: vPlane, height: vImagePixelCount(subsampledHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(subsampledWidth), rowBytes: vStride)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBufferRef!, .readOnly)
        let pixelBufferData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferRef!)
        let rowBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBufferRef!)
        var destinationImageBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
        destinationImageBuffer.data = pixelBufferData
        destinationImageBuffer.height = vImagePixelCount(height)
        destinationImageBuffer.width = vImagePixelCount(width)
        destinationImageBuffer.rowBytes = rowBytes

        var permuteMap: [UInt8] = [3, 2, 1, 0] // BGRA
        let convertError = vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888(&yPlaneBuffer, &uPlaneBuffer, &vPlaneBuffer, &destinationImageBuffer, &infoYpCbCrToARGB, &permuteMap, 255, vImage_Flags(kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole))

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBufferRef!, [])


        yPlane.deallocate()
        uPlane.deallocate()
        vPlane.deallocate()
        let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        print("Decoding time \((end-start)*1000)")
        return convertError

    }
    fileprivate func calculatePlaneSize(forFrame frame: OTVideoFrame)
        -> (ySize: Int, uSize: Int, vSize: Int)
    {
        guard let frameFormat = frame.format
            else {
                return (0, 0 ,0)
        }
        let baseSize = Int(frameFormat.imageWidth * frameFormat.imageHeight) * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size
        return (baseSize, baseSize / 4, baseSize / 4)
    }

}
```

Performance tested on iPhone7, one frame conversion is less than a millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me (I've taken your function and changed it a bit):

```
func createPixelBufferWithVideoFrame(_ frame: OTVideoFrame) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    if let fLock = frameLock {
        fLock.lock()

        let planeSize = calculatePlaneSize(forFrame: frame)

        let yPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.ySize)
        let uPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.uSize)
        let vPlane = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>.allocate(capacity: planeSize.vSize)

        memcpy(yPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 0), planeSize.ySize)
        memcpy(uPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 1), planeSize.uSize)
        memcpy(vPlane, frame.planes?.pointer(at: 2), planeSize.vSize)

        let width = frame.format!.imageWidth
        let height = frame.format!.imageHeight

        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        var err: CVReturn;

        err = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(width), Int(height), kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, nil, &pixelBuffer)
        if (err != 0) {
            NSLog("Error at CVPixelBufferCreate %d", err)
            return nil
        }

        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer {
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            let yPlaneTo = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
            memcpy(yPlaneTo, yPlane, planeSize.ySize)

            let uvRow: Int = planeSize.uSize*2/Int(width)

            let halfWidth: Int = Int(width)/2

            if let uPlaneTo = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1) {
                let uvPlaneTo = uPlaneTo.bindMemory(to: GLubyte.self, capacity: Int(uvRow*halfWidth*2))

                for i in 0..<uvRow {
                    for j in 0..<halfWidth {
                        let dataIndex: Int = Int(i) * Int(halfWidth) + Int(j)
                        let uIndex: Int = (i * Int(width)) + Int(j) * 2
                        let vIndex: Int = uIndex + 1

                        uvPlaneTo[uIndex] = uPlane[dataIndex]
                        uvPlaneTo[vIndex] = vPlane[dataIndex]

                    }
                }

            }

        }

        fLock.unlock()

        return pixelBuffer
    }
    return nil
}
```